# Node JS - Module did not self register

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp, node.js-addon

I went through different posts & most of them suggest to rebuild/reinstall/update npm, which I tried, but of no help.

I'm trying an example of node.js with C++, below are the file details

TestNode.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
class TestNode {
public:
    void printHelloW() {
        std::cout << "Hello World!!!";
    }
};
```

binding.gyp

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "newexample",
      "sources": [ "TestNode.cpp" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now comes the execution & it throws the error saying module is not self registered.

```
D:\newexample>node-gyp configure
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.3.1
gyp info using node@5.10.0 | win32 | x64
gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp info spawn args [ 'C:\\Users\\rtv\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-G',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=auto',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'D:\\newexample\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\rtv\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\rtv\\.node-gyp\\5.10.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\rtv\\.node-gyp\\5.10.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\rtv\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=D:\\newexample',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'D:\\newexample\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info ok

D:\newexample>node-gyp build
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.3.1
gyp info using node@5.10.0 | win32 | x64
gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' ]
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  TestNode.cpp
  win_delay_load_hook.c
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  newexample.vcxproj -> D:\newexample\build\Release\\newexample.node
gyp info ok

D:\newexample>node
> var obj=require("./build/Release/newexample")
Error: Module did not self-register.
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:440:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at repl:1:9
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:269:27)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
>
```

Version Info

```
D:\newexample>node -v
v5.10.0

D:\newexample>npm -v
3.8.3

D:\newexample>node-gyp -v
v3.3.1

OS: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit
```

Request you to guide me in resolving this error.

Comment: Did you fix the problem?If yes means plz post the answer because I too facing the same problem exactly what u asked.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a node.js addon isn't quite that simple, you need to explicitly export functions and call the appropriate macro to register the addon with node's module system. Read the [Addons documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/addons.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Developing an addon for Node.js using node-gyp is a bit tricky. Your .cpp file needs to be very much tailored to work in the Node.js environment.

I suggest starting at the very first "Hello World" example at the [Node.js C/C++ Addons Documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/addons.html#addons_addon_examples).

Here is a (non-exhaustive) list of things missing from your .ccp file.

The Node.js C++ library

```
#include <node.h>
```

An 'init' function which exposes methods to Node.js. Here we can see that calling `addon.hello()` in Javascript will call the `Method` function in C++ (not shown here).

```
void init(Local<Object> exports) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "hello", Method);
}
```

A NODE_MODULE call which defines the addon name and the init function (above). The first parameter of this function (currently `addon`) must match the `"target_name"` value in the `binding.gyp` file. In your case, `newexample`.

```
NODE_MODULE(addon, init)
```

Comment: Here is a full example for reference https://blog.scottfrees.com/building-an-asynchronous-c-addon-for-node-js-using-nan